# Issues with width of "floating" link section

Tags: html, css

I have a list of links on the sidebar of my website that starts out as position: relative, and then when you scroll past the header, it changed to position: fixed. It does so with a short jQuery script that checks the height of the window on scroll and changes the class from "relative" to "fixed" if the height is greater than the height of my header, and corresponding classes in my CSS that change the position attribute. The issue I am having is with the width of the element containing the links. When it is relative, I have the width set to 100% so it fills the sidebar. When it is fixed, width is relative to the window so I set it to width: 25%, which was a close approximation. It worked fine on my screen, however when I tried it on a larger screen the element overlapped the main content area. I then tried changing the CSS to something like the following:

```
.fixed {
   position: fixed;
   left: 15%;
   right: 70%;
}
```

But again, it didn't work properly on a large screen. Any ideas on what to try next? Thanks so much!

EDIT: I tried adding this to my script but it still isn't working:

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() > 150){
        //begin to scroll
    var links = $("#project-links");
    links.attr('class', 'fixed');
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var newLeft = .075 * windowWidth;
    var newRight = .68 * windowWidth;
    var strLeft = newLeft.toString() + 'px';
    var strRight = newRight.toString() + 'px';
    links.css({'left': strLeft, 'right': strRight, 'width': ''});
} else {
    //lock it back into place
    var links = $("#project-links");
    links.attr('class','relative');
    links.css({'left': '', 'right': '', 'width': '100%'});
}
});
```

EDIT 2:
Finally fixed it, I was being stupid. Here is what did the trick:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 150){
    //begin to scroll
    var links = $("#project-links");
    links.attr('class', 'fixed');
    links.css('width', links.parent().width());
}
```

Comment: Would it be out of the question to make the width not a percent?

Comment: I tried that but it still didn't work 100% when I tried it on the big screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed your `.fixed` container is relative to the window when the `position` property is set to `fixed`. Percentage does not help you here, you need absolute values. You have already a script embedded, it could use the width of the parent element and apply it to the `.fixed` element when resizing.

Comment: I tried adding to my script to fix it but still couldn't get it to work (see my edit) any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of using `''` use `'auto'` on attributes like `width`, `left` and `right`. That's the only issue I see here. I don't know if you've calculated the `newLeft` and `newRight` the same way it is set in the parent element but you could debug that using `console.log`.